# How to focus a text field that is not validating?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am working on flutter form and want to focus a text field that is not validating user input means showing error.

[image]

I want that when user enter submit button the "Admission Number" field get automatically focused. And the other issues is that when more than one fields are not validating so how I can only auto focused the first non-validating field.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to focus the first non validated field but I know you can make the listview scroll up using a scrollcontroller

Answer (score 0):

first may you form widget ?
Exam :

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();`
var focusTextField = false;


Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        autofocus:focusTextField ,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == "maybe regex") {
            return null;
          }
          return "Not empty bro";
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
);`
onPress() {
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  //Okay
  setState(() {
    focusTextField = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for contributing, I am trying this one but it is only valid in case if I have one text field that is not validating but not when I have multiple not validating fields.

Comment: Form Field for multiple valid. If you have multiple textformfield  , you can use that field. If maybe, There is not a problem state ( only one field ) you use validator .